# Flutter - NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter, rating, ratingbar, rating-system

I am trying to get lists of averages rating from JSON rest API in Flutter. When there is rating value for all product the listview displays fine but when any product has an empty rating the listview returns an error "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: length. Below is my code;

```
                             ListView.separated(
                                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                      Divider(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                      ),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                  itemCount: content.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                                 final current = content[position];
                                    double myrate = double.parse(content[position].ratings);
                                    return Container(

                                           child: SmoothStarRating(
                                                    allowHalfRating: true,
                                                    onRatingChanged: (v) {
                                                    setState(() {});
                                                     },
                                                    starCount: 5,
                                                    rating: myrate,
                                                    halfFilledIconData: Icons.star_half,
                                                    size: 20.0,
                                                    filledIconData: Icons.star,
                                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                                    borderColor: Colors.orange,
                                                    spacing: 0.0)

                                                     )

                                            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this error by simply adding returning "0" when my rating is empty and the actual value when it is not empty. With this line of code:

```
double myrate = double.parse( content[position].ratings==null ? "0" : content[position].ratings);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should consider all situations in your code. for example when the list is null or it's empty you should show the user something else. you should change your code to something like this:

```
Container(
   child: content.length > 0 
   ? ListView.separated()
   : Text('there is no rate for this ...'),
)
```

if your data is nullable change your condition to this:

```
    Container(
       child: (content?.length ?? 0) > 0 
       ? ListView.separated()
       : Text('there is no rate for this ...'),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, when I used the first code it returns the same error but when I tried the second condition it returns " type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'bool'. "

Comment: @michaelisijola sorry, I fix the issue simply by adding paracentesis.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Payam Zahedi for the effort was able to figure it out by myself with my answer above.